# What logging can I turn on / dump can I retrieve in order to report this bug in Chrome?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, javascript, debug

Once or twice a week, I run into a bug in Chrome where not only all my Chrome tabs, but even all my Chrome windows, appear frozen, due to an invisible Javascript confirmation dialog. I don't know what causes this state, so I don't know how to reproduce it—but when it does happen, I can reproduce it over and over, *e.g.* with a simple `confirm('foobar')` in JSFiddle, until I kill all instances of chrome.exe.

My current instance of Chrome is now in that state. (I learned to "escape" by hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> to select <kbd>Cancel</kbd> on the invisible confirmation dialog, but this only works if the offending dialog occurs on the window and tab that happened to be active.)

What can I do to gather information about the state of Chrome to report this bug? Nothing appears on the Developers' console. This has been happening for about a year now, and since then I've reinstalled Chrome on 3 of my machines (2 of them on clean Windows 7 installations), yet I run into this issue on all machines. I think I happen to notice them more than most because I play an online game that makes use of confirmation dialogs between turn actions, but the issue isn't specific to that site—I've experienced it on other sites, and as I said, I can reproduce it on JSFiddle once it happens once.

Comment: "where not only all my Chrome tabs" - What are you trying to say here? Please work on this sentence its very hard to understand.  I mean you have 5 commas in a single sentence, break it up into complete thoughts, because I can't follow you.

Comment: It might be expected that within a window, a dialog could block the entire window (i.e. not be able to switch tabs). But the scenario actually blocks the thread(s) such that all my Chrome windows are frozen. Maybe this is obvious to some who knows for example that the dialog is handled in a single threaded component that all Chrome instances share. But that's not obvious to me.